# array.reduce is not a function in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am filtering my task list based on date . When i give the custom date  it should display the task list . All the API part works perfectly.

```
groupBy = (array, key) => {
    // Return the end result
    return array.reduce((result, currentValue) => {
        // If an array already present for key, push it to the array. Else create an array and push the object
        (result[currentValue[key]] = result[currentValue[key]] || []).push(
            currentValue
        );
        // Return the current iteration `result` value, this will be taken as next iteration `result` value and accumulate
        return result;
    }, {}); // empty object is the initial value for result object
};
```

The bug i am getting is:'

```
TypeError: array.reduce is not a function
```

Since i am new to this ,  i have no idea  . Any suggestions?

Comment: You aren't passing an array to the function. Best guess you're passing an object. Make sure `array` is actually an array

Comment: Add `console.log(array)` in the first line of the `groupBy` method to know what's the value that `array` is holding.

Comment: If you update your question to include *what* is calling `groupBy` and *what* is being passed, and how *those* objects are instantiated and updated through the component lifecycle we may be better able to assist. Right now we need more debugging details.

Comment: Please add more information.